# Espresso: Not able to launch inner fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-espresso

I am using `launchFragmentInContainer<FragmentOne>()` to launch fragment and able to perform actions using `EspressoMatchers`, it's all working fine.

But the issue comes when I want to launch another fragment onClick Of button(this code is inside `FragmentOne`) but while launching getting an error for FragmentTwo

Example:

```
onClick {
        val fragment = FragmentTwo.newInstance()
        val transaction = requireActivity().supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        transaction.add(fragmentContainerID, fragment)
        transaction.commit()    
       }
```

Above code giving error `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x4d2 (unknown) for fragment FragmentTwo{bc39d06} (6f4636b5-f441-4e38-956a-47ac91d261bc) id=0x4d2}`

How to resolve this inside fragment? or I have to do something in espresso test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is coming due to `fragmentContainerID` which should be unique and used under the hood of `launchFragmentInContainer()`.

So, inside the espresso framework `android.R.id.content` is used as a `fragment Id`. This same id should be used while the fragment transaction.

**Code Snippet:**

```
var fragmentContainerID = android.R.id.content // It will do the trick and fragment will be added on top of stack
```